# TWTweetComposeViewController - animated GIF

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to upload an animated **GIF** with `TWTweetComposeViewController`?

I gave it a try with `UIImage`, and it only uploads the first frame.  This makes sense, since `UIImage` doesn't support animated GIFs.

Is there a way to do this?  Maybe a way to pass an `NSData`?

> (**My app is MonoTouch C#, but Objective-C answers work just as
>   well**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - Twitter's official API documentation **does not allow** animated gif - only png, jpeg and one frame of gif is allowed

Here is their [api doc page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media)

I also tried the example for [TWrequest post using multipart image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034764) set to the raw Gif file and twitter sent back 400 / 403 error message

Answer (score 2):

[Follow This Link http://blog.stijnspijker.nl/2009/07/animated-and-transparent-gifs-for-iphone-made-easy/](http://blog.stijnspijker.nl/2009/07/animated-and-transparent-gifs-for-iphone-made-easy/) It has the library to insert GIF images into UIImageView

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think it solves this problem, since it creates a `UIImageView` and not a `UIImage`.  Looking at the code, it pulls out each frame of a GIF and creates a `UIImage` array to call `[imageView setAnimationImages:array]`.  I already do this by keeping a set of JPGs and the GIF.  This might be good for helping me remove the JPGs, but not post the GIF to Twitter.  I may look at porting this to C# anyway, I can save file space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there isn't a way to do this.