# Post on Twitter in single click - like Instagram

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, share

I'm trying to implement Twitter share the way it is done in Instagram.
What it means is that I want the user to approve the built in Twitter credentials (defined in the iPhone settings) and after that, every time the user clicks a "share" button - it will post a tweet on Twitter without the need for the user to fill the text or see additional dialog like the `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: to achieve this u can use `TWRequest` go through the Q&A in this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034764/use-twrequest-to-send-an-image-with-a-text-to-twitter-in-ios5

Comment: I have mentioned this in the answer, if it worked for you accept it.

Comment: Note that the Twitter framework has been replaced in iOS 6 by the Social framework. The Twitter framework is deprecated in iOS 6 as vishy mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `TWRequest`, go through the Q&A in this post..

[Use TWrequest to send an image with a text to Twitter in IOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034764/use-twrequest-to-send-an-image-with-a-text-to-twitter-in-ios5)

But in iOS 6 this might be deprecated, so check out the adjacent classes used for this purpose.