# What NSData do I need to pass into facebookRequest?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                      URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"]
                                                               parameters:parameters];     


[facebookRequest addMultipartData: @"?"
                                     withName:@"source"
                                     type:@"video/mov"
                                     filename:@"sample_sorenson.mov"];
```

I am trying to share a video called sample_sorenson.mov to Facebook. I don't know NSData it's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_10) for the method `addMultipartData:withName:type:filename:` mentions:

```
Parameters
data
The data for the multipart POST body, such as an image or text.
```

Maybe you can pass an image or a text that you want to be shared together with that video.

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034764/use-twrequest-to-send-an-image-with-a-text-to-twitter-in-ios5#8045798), you can do that in the following way:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_title_here"]);
NSData *textData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your_text_here"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And then you can pass either the text or the data:

```
[facebookRequest addMultipartData: textData
                                   withName:@"source"
                                   type:@"video/mov"
                                   filename:@"sample_sorenson.mov"];
```

Comment: I wish I could test it, but I'm getting denied to Facebook login now, so I will come back to this question later, hopefully soon.